# Confusion Regarding How to Wrap an Execvp Call

Tags: c, process, io

I am having trouble getting complete output of programs called with `execvp`. Here I am basically trying to wrap any program with a program that can filter input and output:

```
#define BUF_SIZ 8192
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int outp[2]; // r, w
    int inp[2];
    pid_t pid;
    char buf[BUF_SIZ];
    fd_set fds;
    struct timeval tv;

    tv.tv_sec = 0;
    tv.tv_usec = 300000;
    if (pipe(outp) < 0 || pipe(inp) < 0) return 1;
    if ((pid = fork()) < 0) return 2;
    else if (pid) {
        close(outp[1]);
        close(inp[0]);
        dup2(outp[0], STDIN_FILENO);
        dup2(inp[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
        execvp(*(argv + 1), argv + 1);
    } else {
        while (1) {
            FD_ZERO(&fds);
            FD_SET(STDIN_FILENO, &fds);
            FD_SET(inp[0], &fds);
            if (select(inp[0] + 1, &fds, NULL, NULL, &tv) < 0) exit(3);
            if (FD_ISSET(STDIN_FILENO, &fds))
                write(outp[1], buf, read(STDIN_FILENO, buf, BUF_SIZ));
            if (FD_ISSET(inp[0], &fds))
                write(STDOUT_FILENO, buf, read(inp[0], buf, BUF_SIZ));
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If i use the program to call a shell `sh`, I get the following output (I do not receive a prompt):

```
$ ./shell sh    
echo "test"
test
^C
```

And if I try to run Python; I receive no output:

```
$ ./shell python
print "test"
^C
```

Why am I not receiving (most) output?

Comment: Are you sure you want to `execvp()` in the *parent*?

Comment: @EOF Ooh, you're right about that. I should have written `if (pid == 0)`.

Comment: I'd do `if (!pid)`, but I'm lazy...

Comment: @EOF That, or just reverse the `if ... else`, and keep the `if (pid)`.

Comment: I'd recommend also handling the case of `fork()` failing.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I do `return 2` upon failing `fork()`. Do you mean some kind of output otherwise?

Comment: @MotokoKusanagi My apologies. I misread the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is, that the stdin of your shell and python interpreter is not a terminal. Both programs behave a bit different in that case:

- The shell does not issue a prompt
- Python wants to read its full script from stdin (until EOF) first

For example, for the python script to work you would have to catch EOF from *your* stdin (read returns 0) and in this case close the stdin of your python process. You can then invoke EOF by pressing CTRL+D on your terminal.

```
if (select(inp[0] + 1, &fds, NULL, NULL, &tv) < 0) exit(3);
if (FD_ISSET(STDIN_FILENO, &fds)) {
    int st = read(STDIN_FILENO, buf, BUF_SIZ));
    if (st > 0)
        write(outp[1], buf, st);
    else {
        close(outp[1]);
    ...
```

If you want to have an interactive terminal you would have to open a new pseudo-terminal, `forkpty(3)` will do most of the work for you.